# StartForegroundService cause IllegalArgumentException

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, foreground-service

I'm trying to send an intent

```
fun enableMode(context: Context) {
    val i = Intent(ACTION_ENABLEMODE)
    i.putExtra(EXTRA_NUMBER, Number)
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        startForegroundService(context, i) //it comes here
    } else {
        startService(context, i)
    }
}
```

After that the app crashes and show message

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit:    Intent { act=com.app.eng.myservice.action.ENABLEMODE (has extras) }
at android.app.ContextImpl.validateServiceIntent(ContextImpl.java:1480)
at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1521)
at android.app.ContextImpl.startForegroundService(ContextImpl.java:1499)
```

Is that an issue on the client app side and I send intent wrong or what might be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
val i = Intent(ACTION_ENABLEMODE)
```

You didn't mention the service class name in the intent as you used [the single arg constructor.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#Intent(java.lang.String))

Assuming the service class name is `MyServiceClass`, then use [the two argument constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#Intent(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.Class%3C?%3E)):

```
val i = Intent(context, MyServiceClass::class.java)
i.action = ACTION_ENABLEMODE
```

Then add the rest of your code.